# keyboard is shown and the predictive text box on the top of the keyboard is toggled the view shoots up leaving a user with a black screen

Tags: ios, swift

I have a bug where when the keyboard is shown and the predictive text box on the top of the keyboard is toggled the view shoots up leaving a user with a black screen. The reason this happens is because I'm using the -= operator, this compounds the value every time this method is called. This method can be called multiple times in a row. I'm trying to find a way to handle this.

```
func getKeyboardHeight(notification: NSNotification) -> CGFloat {

    let userInfo = notification.userInfo
    let keyboardSize = userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
    return keyboardSize.CGRectValue().height

}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    if bottomTextField.isFirstResponder() {
        self.view.frame.origin.y -= getKeyboardHeight(notification)
    }

}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

    if bottomTextField.isFirstResponder() {
        self.view.frame.origin.y += getKeyboardHeight(notification)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By switching the self.view.frame.origin.y -= getKeyboardHeight(notification) to view.frame.origin.y = -getKeyboardHeight(notification) solved my issue.

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    if bottomTextField.isFirstResponder() {
        self.view.frame.origin.y = -getKeyboardHeight(notification)
    }

}
```